# Why was "Lifestyle impact on career" closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I fail to understand why the moderator decided to close this question, even after my edit removing specific instances where the OP was polling for opinons.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/lifestyle-impact-on-career

It had 3 downvotes and 4 close votes before my edit.  A moderator placed the final close vote after my edit.  I honestly don't understand why this question would be closed when a similar question I had posted a while ago was very well received by the community.

[How can frequent anxiety attacks affect me in business and the workplace?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/650/how-can-frequent-anxiety-attacks-affect-me-in-business-and-the-workplace)

*"Will [insert generic personality trait here] affect my career?"* type questions are similar enough that they should either all stay open or all be closed.  I would like to see this question reopened, or my question to be closed for consistency.

Answer (score 8):

The core question in ["Lifestyle impact on career"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/lifestyle-impact-on-career) is this: "Are professionals measured through their perceived lifestyle choices?"

To me, that's unanswerable (because the answer depends on the industry, the company, etc).  If the question were an *actual problem* the OP is facing, such as "My manager has expressed hesitation in promoting me or giving more responsibility to me because I have survival gear in my truck in the company parking lot -- how do I dispel the notion that I am a wild and crazy guy who can't be trusted?" then that's something the community could answer. (Note: In no way do I think survival gear in a truck means anyone is a wild and crazy person who can't be trusted.)  I can think of all sorts of coaching/learning/etc opportunities for that one, including how to express transferable skills to one's manager.

But that's not what the question is, right now.

In your question, ["How can frequent anxiety attacks affect me in business and the workplace?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/650/how-can-frequent-anxiety-attacks-affect-me-in-business-and-the-workplace), I think the core questions (and in fact the question I actually focused on in my answer) are *"will management think me too weak to take charge and be an effective leader?"*  and *"Am I too weak to be a good manager someday?"* This phrasing does lend itself to an "it depends" answer, or even to call the question too localized, but I think the reason it still exists is that it *does* speak to an actual problem faced in the workplace, with actual answers.

Basically, I see a big difference between "Will [insert generic personality trait here] affect my career?" and "This is who I am and what is happening in my workplace everyday, how can I fix/change this?"

Answer (score 3):

It's a discussion. Your edit was extremely minor and removed one of several hints to the fact that the question can not be answered, only discussed. More relevant is the fact that those hints were accurate; it *can* only be discussed as-is hence the close reason and closure.

> I know there is no cookie-cutter type answer to the question "how much does one's projected lifestyle impact their workplace reputation and prospects?" but I would like to hear some feedbacks.

Red flag 1 (not removed by your edit): Feedback, not answers.  The problem isn't that there's no one cookie cutter type answer, but there aren't answers, just opinions (that's not just how it sounds, it's how the question reads as well).

> I am curious on feedback how

Red flag 2 (removed by your edit, but the meaning of the post is otherwise the same)

> And is a "renaissance man" typically someone perceived to be too much all over the place to be trusted to maintain a steady focus of attention?
>
> I have observed that employers favor kind of boring and regular people for their stability in promoting. I hope I am wrong. How does one effectively isolate their life away from work with their career? Or is it an exercise in futility?

Big red flag 1: Multiple questions, largely unrelated. Each of them Bad Subjective and unanswerable too, but I'm getting to that.

Big red flag 2: "Is a renaissance man typically...":

- What's a renaissance man? Without an agreed definition this is NARQ and invites debate
- "typically seen" by who?
- What's the problem you're solving? It's a discussion, not a search for a solution

Big red flag 3: "How does one effectively isolate their life away from work with their career? Or is it an exercise in futility?"

From the FAQ:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Entire books could be written on this topic (I'm sure there are several Self Help books on this *exact* topic). It's *way* too huge for one question. Additionally it's still Bad Subjective; it's soliciting opinion.

This question has all kinds of problems as a question, and solving *all* of them would more or less require completely rewriting the question and compeltely altering it's scope and intent.